# Filtering Fullcalendar by dropdown jQuery AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

I have a fullcalendar application, which displays events from JSON. It works fine at this point, but I need to filter the calendar depending the selected value in a dropdown when I press the filtering button. It doesn't load events for the selected item. This is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  
    var base_url = 'http://localhost:8080/';
    var idCentro = 11;
    llenaCboProfesionales();
    configCalendar();
    
    //press the button after selecting an item from dropdown
    $('#btnFiltrar').on('click',function(e){
  
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        var idProfesional = $('#cboProfesional').val();
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
            },
          lang: 'es',
          editable: true,
          header: {
              left: 'prev,next today',
              center: 'title',
              right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
          },
          defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
          eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
          events: {
              url: base_url +'/alleventsByProf/'+idProfesional,
              type: 'GET',
          },
      }
});
      
//config calendar on load event, so I don't have select a value from dropdown for displaying it... I know this a terrible practice
function configCalendar() {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        lang: 'es',
        editable: true,
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
        events: {
                  
        },            
    });

    //loads dropdown
    function llenaCboProfesionales() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'get',
            url: base_url + 'profesional/get-by-centro/'+idCentro,
            success: function(data) {
                $('#cboProfesional').empty();
                $.each(data,function(key, registro) {
                    $('#cboProfesional').append('<option value='+registro.id+'>'+registro.prof+'</option>');
                });        
            }
        });
    }
});
```

View Calendar.html:

```
<div>
    <label>Profesional:</label>
    <select id="cboProfesional" class="form-control" name="cboProfesional">      
    </select>
    <br>
    <button type="button" name="btnFiltrar" id="btnFiltrar" class="btn btn-primary">Ver Agenda</button>
</div>
    
<div class="col-xs-9" id='calendar'>  
</div>
```

How could I filter the calendar after selecting a value and pressing the button?  and also make it render events on load event depending the default selected value on dropdown?

Comment: Can you open developer tools by pressing F12 and check if the request is made to `http://localhost:8080/alleventsByProf/` url, when you press the filter button? If the request is made can you check if the URL is returning correct json data?

Comment: `$('#calendar').fullCalendar({` recreates the whole calendar again every time your filter button is clicked. This is really inefficient. You don't need to do it like that. Just configure the "events" feed to collect your filter parameter from its source each time, and then use the refetchEvents method to trigger a new query to the server. See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/events-json-feed (specifically the "dynamic data parameter" section) and also https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/refetchEvents for more details

Comment: http://localhost:8080/alleventsByProf/ is returning the correct data depending the selected value, but is not refreshing the calendar. I can't pass only the "events" property and is not loading the whole calendar

Comment: " I can't pass only the "events" property "...I'm not sure what this means. Did you understand my suggestion? Did you try it?